# jOOQ - error with alias and quotes

Tags: java, sql, h2, jooq

I have this query:

```
Field<String> yearMonth = DSL.field("FORMATDATETIME({0}, 'yyyy-MM')",
                    String.class, LICENZE.CREATION_DATE).as("anno_mese");

List<Record3<Integer, String, String>> records = 
    create.select(DSL.count().as("num_licenze"), LICENZE.EDIZIONE, yearMonth).
    from(LICENZE).
    groupBy(LICENZE.EDIZIONE, yearMonth).
    orderBy(yearMonth).
    fetch();
```

this query generates:

```
select 
  count(*) "num_licenze", 
  "PUBLIC"."LICENZE"."EDIZIONE", 
  FORMATDATETIME("PUBLIC"."LICENZE"."CREATION_DATE", 'yyyy-MM') "anno_mese"
from "PUBLIC"."LICENZE"
group by 
  "PUBLIC"."LICENZE"."EDIZIONE", 
  "anno_mese"
order by "anno_mese" asc
```

executing it i get: `Column "anno_mese" not found; SQL statement`

Testing the generated query and removing the quotes from `anno_mese` in every parts of the query make the query works instead.

Is my query wrong or am I using jooq in the wrong way?

The alias in this query is not so important, I can run the query without using it too but just to understand how it works.
I am using h2 as database.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I suspect this is a bug in H2, which I've reported here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/QE3wU2CNgmg), because the query looks fine to me. Here are some workarounds that you can do from the jOOQ side:

#### Don't reference the `"anno_mese"` column by name

While SQL is a bit repetitive otherwise, you won't notice the difference with jOOQ. I simply moved the `as("anno_mese")` method call into the `SELECT` clause. You don't really need it in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
Field<String> yearMonth = DSL.field("FORMATDATETIME({0}, 'yyyy-MM')",
                    String.class, LICENZE.CREATION_DATE);

List<Record3<Integer, String, String>> records = 
    create.select(DSL.count().as("num_licenze"), 
                  LICENZE.EDIZIONE, 
                  yearMonth.as("anno_mese")).
    from(LICENZE).
    groupBy(LICENZE.EDIZIONE, yearMonth).
    orderBy(yearMonth).
    fetch();
```

#### Disable quoting in jOOQ generated queries

You can use [jOOQ's `Settings`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/) to prevent [schema / table / column names from being quoted](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/). Example:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2, 
    new Settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);
```

#### Use upper case column names

This will probably work: `DSL.field(...).as("ANNO_MESE")`